# New RadRails project in Eclipse with SQL Server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, aptana, radrails

I'm trying to get into Rails development and am using Aptana Studio (RadRails) as a plugin to Eclipse (WinXP).  When I create a new project with the options shown here

[NewRailsProject http://www.sqeq.com/image/NewRailsProject.jpg](http://www.sqeq.com/image/NewRailsProject.jpg)

things go south.  I get this error right away:

[alt text http://www.sqeq.com/image/NewRailsProject2.jpg](http://www.sqeq.com/image/NewRailsProject2.jpg)

Mongrel's set as the default server and it's complaining about starting because of a missing log file.  Sure enough, nearly the entire project skeleton is non-existent.

Going through the same exercise with another dbms selected in the New Project screen worked just fine and I have been able to hack through things to get my project switched over from MySQL to SQL Server by installing the MS jdbc driver and getting the ADO.rb file copied into my Ruby install ala [this post](http://justinram.wordpress.com/category/ruby/ruby-on-rails/).

Is there a trick to getting RadRails to do this without the aforementioned workarounds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to say, while this is not a specific response to your question, that I was not impressed with radrails when I last looked at it.  It was built on an old version of eclipse and was pretty painful to use.

You might look around stackoverflow for some other ide choices: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=ide+rails.

Comment: Yeah, I'm thinking that you're probably correct here after playing with it some more.  I might just pony-up for RubyMine or something else instead.  Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure what your level of knowledge of ruby is, but if you are new, you might try just using a basic text editor (vim, et al) so you have to suffer the burden of finding files and learning the apis.  

You know in math class where they always teach you the hard way first.  I think it applies here as well.